# 'H' key malfunctioning on a Dell Vostro 3568 Laptop with Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, dell-vostro

When I press <kbd>H</kbd> on an editor, it types the <kbd>H</kbd> character and then some other tab gets activated. Like if the text editor is in focus, after pressing <kbd>H</kbd>, the focus changes to somewhere else on the window. Whenever this happens on the command prompt, it types <kbd>^Z</kbd> automatically there.

What is causing the issue and how can I fix it?
My laptop is a Dell Vostro 3568.

Comment: What editor? Does the software matter or does it do this on every software?

Comment: @music2myear No, any text editor for that matter. While typing this comment, I had issues. Be it typing any URL on browser, or typing anywhere.

Comment: A way to help possibly sort out if this is a hardware or software problem might be to plugin a cheap keyboard and see if the issue persists.

Comment: What @Anaksunaman says then. It's likely hardware, and it is simple to test this. If a different keyboard does not have the issue the problem is with your keyboard. If it does not solve the problem you likely need to check for firmware and driver updates, or new drive maps (less likely), or reimage the computer.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I don't think it's hardware. This issue comes and goes automatically after some time. Right now, it is working fine, but yesterday it was a problem. This has happened twice.
Also, I tried an external keyboard, there wasn't an issue.